# Hibernate SchemaFilterProvider get Java entity name

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like Hibernate to  disable certain classes from being validated on startup.

My particular use-case:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

```
@Table (name = "SAME_TABLE")
public class Entity1 {
   @Column
   private Long value;

   // rest of values
}

@Table (name = "SAME_TABLE")
public class SearchEntity2 {
   @Column
   private String value;

   // rest of values
}
```

As you can see I have two classes mapped to the same table called `SAME_TABLE`. This is because I want to do wildcard searches on numeric field `value`

JPA Validation fails on Oracle (h2 succeeds suprisingly) because it detects that the `String` is not `NUMERIC(10)`.

This question here by @b0gusb provides an excellent way of filtering out via table name:
[How to disable schema validation in Hibernate for certain entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212144/how-to-disable-schema-validation-in-hibernate-for-certain-entities)

Unfortunately my table name is identical. Is there any way of getting to the Java class name from `SchemaFilter`or perhaps another way of doing this?

Thanks
X